# Keyboard Shortcut to Fill Right in Numbers?

Tags: keyboard, numbers

In Numbers, is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut to Excel's "Fill Right" <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> and "Fill Down" <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to

```
Systems Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > +
```

to add a shortcut, select or add Numbers as the Application, and put "Fill Down" (exact, no quotes) in the command spot and then assign your shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>)